# Reading in a transparent image by keeping color #000000

Tags: opencv

I need to read a transparent image for further operations, but when I read the image, it seems like it filters out the #000000 color parts, that is the outline I'm willing to keep. How can I read in the image to keep the outline of it, I don't, want to change the color to a bit grayer, only if there is no other way.

I am reading the image like this:
`img2 = cv.imread('2.png')`

[before, after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6q12U.png)

Answer (score 0):

by default, imread() will return only the bgr part of your image. use:

```
img2 = cv.imread('2.png', cv.IMREAD_UCHANGED)
```

to retain the alpha channel